# Maximizing Pair Matchings in Integer-Interval Associations

Tags: algorithm

Consider the scenario where we are given a collection of n integers. These integers are unordered and may include duplicates. Additionally, we have a set of m ranges, each defined by two integers representing the lower and upper boundaries of the interval. Similar to the integers, these intervals are unordered and duplicates are allowed.

The objective is to create pairs between the integers and the intervals under the following conditions:

An integer can only be matched with an interval if it falls within the range of the interval. For instance, the number 4 can be paired with the interval [3, 10], but not with [5, 10].
Each integer is allowed to pair with only one interval, and vice versa.
The goal is to maximize the total number of such pairs.
We are solely interested in determining the maximum number of possible pairs, rather than identifying the specific pairings.

For illustration:

Given a single number 2 and an interval [4, 10], there would be no possible pairing, resulting in an output of 0.
With the number 2 and an interval [2, 10], a single pair can be formed, leading to an output of 1.
For numbers 3, 7, 8, 12 and intervals [0, 10], [5, 15], [20, 25], the maximum number of pairs that can be formed is 2.

While a straightforward approach might involve an algorithm with time complexity of O(nm), the challenge lies in devising a more efficient solution. The question is whether it's feasible to construct an algorithm with a time complexity of O(max(nlog(n), mlog(m), nlog(m), m*log(n))), thereby optimizing the process of determining the maximal number of pairs.